# Retrieving a ParseFile from within a ParseObject - Android C# Xamarin Parse

Tags: c#, android, audio, parse-platform, xamarin

I've been struggling with this for a while now. I've managed to create an app using Xamarin & C# (for android). The app successfully sends a voice recording to my Parse folder(https://parse.com/). From the dashboard on the parse website, I can download the sound file and play it successfully.

I need to be able to download and play the sound from within the app though.
So far, I can retrieve the parseObject that contains the parseFile containing the sound in bytes. I don't know how to go into that parseObject and extract the file though.

Here's how I send the data:

```
 byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(LoadPath);

ParseFile file = new ParseFile(savetheFile, data);

await file.SaveAsync();

var auidoParseObject = new ParseObject("AudioWithData");
//Console.WriteLine(ParseUser.getUserName());

if (ParseUser.CurrentUser != null)
                {
                    tempUserName = ParseUser.CurrentUser.Username.ToString();
                }

else
                {
                    tempUserName = "Anonymous";
                }
                Console.WriteLine("PARSE USERNAME: " + tempUserName);
                auidoParseObject["userName"] = tempUserName;
                auidoParseObject["file"] = file;
                await auidoParseObject.SaveAsync();
```

And here's my attempt to retrieve it form the parse cloud:

```
var query1 = ParseObject.GetQuery ("AudioWithData")
                .WhereEqualTo ("userName", username);

IEnumerable<ParseObject> results1 = await query1.FindAsync();

Console.WriteLine ("At 0:" + results1.ElementAt (0).ToString ());
            Console.WriteLine("At 1:" + results1.ElementAt (1).ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("At 2:" + results1.ElementAt (2).ToString());
```

Here, the console will write:
    At 0:Parse.ParseObject
    At 1:Parse.ParseObject
    At 2:Parse.ParseObject

I now need to extract the "file" part of that parseObject... but HOW!?

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var file = results1[0].Get<ParseFile>("file");
byte[] data = await new HttpClient().GetByteArrayAsync(file.Url);
```

Comment: Hi Jason, sorry for my delay in getting back to you. I've got the following error:  Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Parse.ParseObject>' (CS0021)

Comment: Hi again, sorry, I was a bit hasty to comment there, I used this line instead var myfile = results1.ElementAt(0).Get<ParseFile>("file"); and it appears to be OK. However I only have an emulator at my disposal at the moment. I'll mark this as correct once I've tried it with an android device. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code below to get your files from parse, I  used this code and is working fine to me.

```
public static Task<IEnumerable<YourModel>> GetFiles(UserName userName)
    {
        return new ParseQuery<YourModel> ()
            .Where (x => x.userName == userName)
            .FindAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Hi Ricardo, I'm sorry but I'm a bit of a c# noob... I'm more familiar with VB.NET, so I have a grasp on the .NET framework, but I'm a little confused with the method you've provided. Could you be a little more specific please? Thanks.

Comment: you can retrieve the object with the above method, to get all their properties for example you can use this code "GetFiles.File.Url".